# Is it possible to avoid rendering the error message from an ASP.Net validator control until the validator is evaluated as invalid?

Tags: asp.net, css, section508

Considering the fact that I was not able to find a single instance of someone else needing this functionality anywhere else, this *might* be an off the wall requirement. That said:

A website that I am working on uses several dozen different validator controls (everything from RequiredFieldValidaotrs to CustomValidators) throughout for form validation. As part of our Section 508 compliance, we have to support users who disable CSS, which is problematic because the validators render the error text to the page and use the CSS display property to hide it. When CSS is disabled all of the error messages are both visible and read by screen readers.

Short of using labels and postbacks to show and hide said labels, is there any known method for using ASP.Net validator controls with CSS disabled?

Comment: This kind of stuff is why I will never willingly go back to WebForms. MVC all the way now.

Comment: If only we could. Unfortunately this is for a government website and attempts to change anything tends to move at the speed of government.

Comment: Geneb, I don't know what position you're in, either internal or external contractor, but use the appropriate channels to get in touch with somebody with 508 power in the agency. Some agencies may tell you the site must work/look exactly the same with CSS on or off. Another agency may tell you that the page still has to be functionable with CSS off. The Standards outlined in Section 508 were made back in 2001, and not all assistive technology played nicely with CSS.

Comment: This is more suited to a comment than an answer.

Comment: Agreed, would be better as a comment. As a reply: This has already gone through the client's 508 tests and they have created this defect as a "Must Address" defect, which only gives me two options: Fix it or try long and hard enough that they give up and add it to the "will not comply" list.

Comment: @Graham, I wanted to give it as a comment, but it wouldn't let me.

Comment: @Geneb I'd explain how most people using assistive technology  browse with CSS on, how 508 was created long ago, and at worst it would create extra jumble for AT users.

Comment: @Ryan B It won't make any difference to them. The regulations are followed to the letter (with some extra voluntarily added in since we have an inordinate number of disabled users) and § 1194.22 contains "Documents shall be organized so they are readable without requiring an associated style sheet.". Errors always being displayed without a style sheet definitely goes against that one.

Comment: I would ask if the document must be functionable without it. Those are two different things. If they say no, i would throw the errors down at the bottom, the move them around through the power of CSS/JS when enabled.

Comment: That's an interesting point about moving them to the bottom to preserve readability, Ryan.

Comment: Thanks Graham. To follow up, if they say yes it still has to be functionable, I would throw up a concern flag and ask why. Disclosure: I work for an agency and help with issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Display="None"` attribute on the FieldValidator control and a `ValidationSummary` tag to contain the messages.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1"  /> <br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox2"  /> <br />
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Go"  />

        <div class="messages">
            <asp:ValidationSummary id="summery1"  runat="server"/>
        </div>

        <div>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" >
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"  runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Required Field Validator1 empty" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="None" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2"  runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Required Field Validator2 empty" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" Display="None" />
        </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </form>
```

HOWEVER....(there's always a catch)... with this method, the Validation Messages themselves are stored in the JavaScript only. Meaning that it won't work if Javascript is disabled. I'm assuming that's not a huge problem since you are working in WebForms (which rely on JS), but I figure it's worth mentioning.

And for the record, accessibility concerns are mostly a crock of horse-crap. I THOUGHT I knew about accessibility until I actually worked with a visually impaired programmer (100% blind). Then, I learned that JS works just fine (assuming they know to look for new content...) and that they just skip around the page from link to link until they find what they are after. And table-based layouts didn't slow them down for 1 second. Boy that was a tough pill to swallow after being SOOO unbearably preachy about CSS for a few years....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already tried going with the validation summary, but they shot that down saying that all of the error messages need to be next to the form field where the error exists (for 508 purposes of course). And don't get me started on 508 requirements... I tell every new employee on my team that we have to deal with them when developing, but to not stress out too much because they aren't grounded in reality to begin with. Just one of those many annoying aspects of working on government websites. This may end up being the only true answer to this question, though.

Comment: downvoted re: "accessibilitty issues are crap". A good deal of programmers are power users, so they can zip through a page way faster than your regular user. Saying accessibility issues are crap these days are akin to saying the same about security.

Comment: @geneb, there isn't no set standard about location of errors. The key is equivelent access. So people using assistive tech must know form element x has an error, why it does, and bonus point if you allow them to get to that element quickly. see: http://webaim.org/techniques/formvalidation/

Comment: @Geneb looks like you are going to be rolling your own validation messages and rendering them as needed. It will be tedious, but not overly difficult fortunately.